# Is there a way to perform non-blocking SQL reads in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am currently running a number of SQL queries on the same table in Oracle. It seems to be taking forever to run the queries. My understanding is that Oracle doesn't lock tables just to read data, however this makes me think that it is blocking. I don't care about the state of the data in the table as long as it returns a correct snapshot. Is there a way to run queries that are non-blocking?

Comment: Really this is a performance question. It might have nothing to do with blocking and everything to do with lack of indexes. You should undertake some investigation and post results. What does the query look like? what does the execution plan look like? Does the table have indexes? how many rows in the biggest table? How many rows returned? how long does it take?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately the table exists in a data warehouse, and I have no control over the table structure themselves. I can't add indexes. So you are correct, it could be simply to do with the lack of indexes. It did seem to run better when the queries ran synchronously, one after the other, hence my query.

Comment: It might be that the Oracle server is underpowered (that's kinda unheard of). Data warehouses are generally optimised for reads though. I can't say for sure whether parallel reads on the same table would cause locking issues. At a guess, no, the problem is somewhere else. Anyway you need to graduate from "seem to" to taking some timings and working out if it actually did take longer.

Comment: I will look at timings. As far as the server being under powered, I doubt whether that would be the case. But could it be possible that my account itself has had its resources limited?

Comment: Readers never block other transactions in Oracle

Comment: I'm no Oracle DBA but I believe it does have a resource manager module. You'll probably need to get the query plan to understand any further. If your query plan has any full scans on large table then you might have something to work with. I don't know if you can identify resource manager limiting in the query plan. Lets just wait for a proper DBA to put their 2c in

Comment: Oracle does not allow reads to block writes (or other reads for that matter). This explains it - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149350/why-oracle-doesnt-have-nolock/149395#149395.  Have you any evidence that the blocking is occurring or are you just assuming ?

Comment: I was just assuming. It probably isn't blocking, it's more likely to be because it had no indexes and it's a huge table.